# Knockout.js sort an array and place a particular element as default value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, knockout.js

I have an observable array.

```
var myArray = ko.observable([]);
myArray = ["Apple" , "Orange" , "Grapes" , "Pineapple" , "None" , "Dates" ];
```

Below code will sort this array in alphabetical order.

```
myArray.Sort()
```

After sorting , I want to place the item "None" as the first item(in first position).

Please suggest!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using a regular array wrapped in a `ko.observable` isn't really common.

When you modify the array, knockout will **not** notify subscribers automatically. The code you've posted (even without the "None" custom rule), won't trigger UI updates:

### Non-working example to show the problem:

```js
var myArray = ko.observable([]);
myArray = ["Apple" , "Orange" , "Grapes" , "Pineapple" , "None" , "Dates" ];

ko.applyBindings({ arr: myArray });

myArray.sort();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: arr">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

If you use an `observableArray` instead, the code *will* work:

### Example that shows how `observableArray` works:

```js
var myArray = ko.observableArray([]);

myArray(["Apple" , "Orange" , "Grapes" , "Pineapple" , "None" , "Dates" ]);

ko.applyBindings({ arr: myArray });

myArray.sort();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: arr">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Now, to make sure your array is always sorted, I propose a new `ko.computed` layer:

### Example that shows a typical "knockout way" of doing this:

```js
var myData = ko.observableArray([]);
var sortedDataWithNone = ko.computed(function() {
    return ["None"].concat(myData().sort());
});

ko.applyBindings({ arr: sortedDataWithNone });

myData(["Apple" , "Orange" , "Grapes" , "Pineapple", "Dates" ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: arr">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort first by `None` and the by the string itself.

```js
var myArray = ["Apple", "Orange", "Grapes", "Pineapple", "None", "Dates"];

myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b === 'None') - (a === 'None') || a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(myArray);
```